# Merging duplicate data in an asp.net repeater with data from an access database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I am trying to merge data within a repeater so that all the profiles with the same "Item Name" and time are listed under the item all at once. 
At the moment, the data is being displayed like:

> **9:30 Item Name**
>
> Profile 1
>
> **9:30 Item Name**
>
> Profile 2

But my aim is to display the data as:

> **9:30 Item Name**
>
> Profile 1
>
> Profile 2

[Link to how the html is currently laid out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLW6P.jpg)

ASPX FILE:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptAgenda" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="agenda_card"/>
        <div class="time"><%#Eval("valuefield")%></div>
        <div class="title"><%#Eval("Product")%></div>
        <%#Eval("details")%>
        <a href="#" class="profile_outer">
        <div style="background-image:url('<%#"/photo/" + Eval("photo").ToString()%>');" ></div>
        <%# Eval("type") %></br><b><%#Eval("Name")%>&nbsp;<%#Eval("lastname")%>,&nbsp;<%#Eval("jobtitle")%>
        ><%#Eval("subcompany")%>,&nbsp;<%#Eval("country")%>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

C# FILE:

```
public partial class agenda_code : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  OleDbCommand cmd;
  OleDbConnection con;
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      string dbPath = Server.MapPath("~") + "\\Database\\maindb.accdb";
      con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + dbPath + ";Persist Security Info=False;");

      fillAgenda();
  }

  private void fillAgenda()
  {
      string query = "Select listRecipients.valuefield, listRecipients.Product, listRecipients.type, listRecipients.details, Subscribers.Name, Subscribers.lastname, Subscribers.jobtitle, Subscribers.subcompany, Subscribers.country, Subscribers.photo, Subscribers.ContactBio FROM listRecipients ";
      query += "LEFT JOIN Subscribers ON listRecipients.idEmail=Subscribers.idEmail ";
      query += "Where idList=2830 AND (type <> 'Delegate' AND type <>'Sponsor') order by valuefield";

      OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
      System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
      adp.Fill(ds);
      rptAgenda.DataSource = ds;
      rptAgenda.DataBind();
  }
}
```

Hope I'm not being too vague but any response would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would accomplish in the following.

1. Create a model
2. Call the database, return `IEnumerable<Model>`
3. Then I would filter the data collection
4. Bind the filtered contents to the repeater

In essence you would have a simple object, the unfiltered result set would be returned.  Then use Linq to sanitize, group, or whatever you wish to achieve.

```
var collection = dbContext.GetSample();
var filter = collection.Where(sample => sample.Item == "Data");

rptSample.DataSource = filter;
rptSample.Bind();
```

You'll want to use the proper Linq query to achieve your data result.  However, you could potentially achieve this with a better dataset from the database.  Then you could simply bind, but without structure or understanding of your data those would be my two recommended approaches.

**Update:**

You would create an object that pertains to your business logic, for example.

```
public class Product
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

So you would pull the model from the database.  I've abstracted this out, to reflect the database call.  But that is all this logic is doing.

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
{
     using(var context = factory.Create())
          yield return context.RetrieveAllProducts();
}
```

So, we have a method within a class to retrieve our products.  Inside the page load, you would do the following:

```
var products = productService.GetAllProducts().Where(product => product.Name.Contains("box"));
```

Note that contains isn't case sensitive, not ideal but this is an example.  So, I've called all our products and only want the ones with a name that contains box.  So, now I'll put these into a control.

```
rptProducts.DataSource = products;
rptProducts.DataBind();
```

So the model represents our object, we use the control to reflect the desired content to our page.  This has some benefits, primarily you have a single model to reflect your business logic.  You also receive the benefit of being able to pull an object once, then cache, then use elsewhere also.  Drawbacks do a exists, but you can often overcome, just have to find the proper usage that fits for your application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However I am a bit stuck on how i would create the models. Would i create the models based on the queries? Or are the queries now redundant.

Comment: I’m driving, I’ll reply in an hour

Comment: @unearthlyed Updated, with an example.